# Calculate the difference in dates in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in which there are 3 columns `Alertdate`, `AppointmentDate` and `ID`. The id is not unique and there multiple occurrences for alert and appointment. I want to calculate the difference in `Alertdate` and `AppointmentDate` but only for the first occurrence of `ID`. Example

```
ID  Alertdate  AppointmentDate  NBD

*1   01/01/2000    04/01/2000        3*

1   02/01/2000    04/01/2000        2

*2   01/01/2000    04/01/2000        3*

2   01/01/2000    05/01/2000        4
```

For the above sample data I just need row1 and row3 in my resulting output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you need to calculate NBD first

```
dat=read.table(text="
ID Alertdate AppointmentDate NBD
1 01/01/2000 04/01/2000 3
1 02/01/2000 04/01/2000 2
2 01/01/2000 04/01/2000 3
2 01/01/2000 05/01/2000 4",h=T)

dat$Alertdate=as.Date(dat$Alertdate,format="%d/%m/%Y")
dat$AppointmentDate=as.Date(dat$AppointmentDate,format="%d/%m/%Y")
dat$NBD=as.numeric(dat$AppointmentDate-dat$Alertdate)
```

In case the table is not sorted

```
dat=dat[order(dat$ID,dat$Alertdate),]
```

finally

```
do.call(rbind,by(dat,list(dat$ID),function(x){x[1,]}))
  ID  Alertdate AppointmentDate NBD
1  1 01/01/2000      04/01/2000   3
2  2 01/01/2000      04/01/2000   3
```